# Visual Studio Code C++ Linux Library's On Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So basically I am writing a socket program in C++ on a Windows machine. But I am running a WSL and compile the code within the WSL because I am building it for Linux machines. My only concern is, when I am writing my code in Visual Studio Code, <socket.h> and other Linux libraries of course are not recognized because I'm on a Windows system. Is there any way I can add those to the includePath and they will be recognized within my Visual Studio Code on Windows?

Comment: have you checked their documentation? The include path settings can be seen there [Using C++ and WSL in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl). [Developing in WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl), [Get started using Visual Studio Code with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode)

Comment: See also [An In Depth Tutorial on Linux Development on Windows with WSL and Visual Studio Code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/an-in-depth-tutorial-on-linux-development-on-windows-with-wsl-and-visual-studio-code/), [WSL and VS Code: code on Linux on a Windows laptop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/vs-code-livestreams/wsl-and-vs-code-code-on-linux-on-a-windows-laptop)